# Android NDK configurations

Tags: android, android-ndk

When compiling a windows app with VS, I can choose between `debug` and `release`. I often get a 10x increase in speed using release. Is there such an option to set when compiling an NDK app for Android? Or is it always `release` (or always `debug`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build in release or debug using the APP_OPTIM variable in your Application.mk file.

```
APP_OPTIM := debug
```

or

```
APP_OPTIM := release
```